# Correct translation of 1 Samuel 13:14 especially the words "איש כלבבו"

Tags: words, translation, samuel-shmuel-book-of

What is the correct way to understand [1 Samuel 13:14](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.13.14)?

I particularly want to know about the words "איש כלבבו". Do these words translate to "a man after his own heart" or should it be "a man with a heart like his"

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Elias, and thanks for bringing us your question. I edited your question a bit for clarity, including adding a link to the text online. If there's anything you want to change, just click [edit]. Hope to see you around. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Targum Yonatan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Jonathan), the chief traditional translator of the books of the Prophets, [translates](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=99) this phrase into Aramaic as "גְבַר עָבֵיד רְעוּתֵהּ", which means "a man who does His will." So, "a man after His own heart" would be a reasonable colloquial and literal translation, and indeed is the one chosen by the [JPS 1917 translation](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel) that was linked into the question.

Comment: On what basis do you attribute capitalization to _Yonasan_?

Comment: @msh210, the antecedent of that pronoun seems obvious, in context.